# configure squid with windows 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, squid

I have a 3 pc (192.168.1.2,..3,..4) and a windows 2008 server (192.168.1.100) router is 192.168.1.1.

I just want that the 3 pc set like gateway 192.168.1.100, are filter by squid proxy loaded in win2008

so in win2008 I 've set in control panel the proxy 192.168.1.100:3128 and in win2008 browser work, the connection is filtered by proxy, but in 3 pc not works, so maybe I should route all incoming request into squid, but I dunno how ...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to route the HTTP traffic to the proxy, you have two options:

1. You can configure the web browsers on the PCs to use the proxy. Every web browser enables you to do so.
2. You can redirect the traffic on your gateway/router to the proxy and configure the proxy to enable transparent proxying.

Comment: 2- You can redirect the traffic on your gateway/router to the proxy and configure the proxy to enable transparent proxying. the problem is that i can't figure out todo this :)

Comment: @G.a.r.y, if you want us to help with that you will need to tell us about your router...  P.S. the extra punctuation in your name makes it more difficult to reply to you.

Comment: Sorry maybe I'm not explained very well, I want route (with windows 2008 with command route or netsh no ruoter) all incoming connection on port 8080 of win2008 server I have no access to router thanks :)

Comment: I see that the easiest way is to configure all 3 PCs to use the proxy on win2008. Did you check the squid log file access.log to confirm whether the requests are coming to the server or not?

Comment: yes squid work nicely, the problem is that I don't know how using command route and netsh, but I'm studing :) thanks